# Перебирать порты для соединения по ssh в Ansible

Tags: ansible

Есть, к примеру, хост:

```
[api]
10.0.0.1 ansible_connection=ssh ansible_ssh_user=root ansible_ssh_port=22
```

Здесь мы указываем `22` порт для ssh. Но на некоторых серверных стоит другой порт, скажем `220`.

Возможно как-то задать дополнительный порт для соединения по ssh на случай, если не смог присоединиться по `22`? Каким-нибудь списком, чтоб Ansible по очереди перебирал.

Comment: А вы заранее знаете, какой там порт или нужно именно перебор?

Comment: [How to handle SSH port changes with Ansible?](http://serverfault.com/q/545978)

Comment: @NickVolynkin одно из 2-х: либо 22, либо 220.

Comment: ну вот по сылке как раз решение этой задачи.

Comment: @NickVolynkin сейчас опять понадобилось, доковырял решение :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Частично воспользовался примером от Nick Volynkin.

Вначале плейбука проверяем порты, выбираем тот, что доступен и устанавливаем в `ansible_ssh_port`, после чего Ansible будет уже подсоединяться к машине по этому порту. Единственный минус - использованием `wait_for`. То есть, в данном случае мы ждём 15 секунд (т.к. проверяем 3 порта), пока порты проверятся.

```
- name: just test
  hosts: server
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    list_of_ssh_ports: [22, 220, 234]
  tasks:
    - name: test ssh on port
      sudo: no
      local_action: wait_for port={{item}} timeout=5 host={{inventory_hostname}}
      register: ssh_checks
      with_items: "{{list_of_ssh_ports}}"
      ignore_errors: true
    - debug: msg = "{{item}}"
      with_items: "{{ssh_checks.results}}"
    - name: set available ansible_ssh_port 
      sudo: no
      set_fact: ansible_ssh_port={{item.item}}
      when: ssh_checks is defined and {{item.elapsed}} < 5
      with_items: "{{ssh_checks.results}}"
- hosts: server
  roles:
    - остальные таски
```