# Ansible networks

Tags: ansible, cisco, hp

Задача такая есть 350 коммутаторов, как заставить Ansible запустить команды на всех. Но при этот на некоторые есть доступ по SSH через Tacacs а на другое только под локальной учеткой. Можно ли как-то сказать Ansible делай под этой учеткой и задать условие, если не пустило то открыть новую SSH сессию, под такой-то учеткой?

Comment: Наверное как-то так: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/469946/191416, но вообще - надо привести всю сеть к общему знаменателю.

Comment: Чем собственно и занимаюсь :) Хочу чтобы всё сидело на такаксе.

Comment: А. Ну т.е. это единичная акция? Ну тогда нужно просто с разными логинами\пассами кинуть `ping` и записать всех, кто отозвался. Их `ввести в домен` (в терминологии Active Directory) и так далее. Для одного раза для 350 железок ты дольше будешь искать красивое решение, чем в полуручном режиме переведёшь всё в единообразие. Потом - да, АРХИТЕКТУРА. А щас просто сделай костыль.